# Structure of proto projects

Tags: webots

I have multiple Webots projects which are managed in each git repository.

How can I import the projects into git submodules so that I can put different types of robots into a project?

The projects have the following structure:

```
robotA repo
  \controllers
  \protos
  \worlds
robotB repo
  \controllers
  \protos
  \worlds
project repo
  \controllers
    \robotA -- copied from robotA repo/controllers
    \robotB -- copied from robotB repo/controllers
  \protos
    \robotA -- copied from robotA repo/protos
    \robotB -- copied from robotB repo/protos
  \worlds
```

I'm manually importing the proto files and controllers but it's too error-prone and not easy to track the changes.

I'm trying to use git submodules but I don't think git supports to import only a subdirectory of a submodule.

Can I set an environment variable where a Webots project finds protos?
Or any suggestions on managing multiple robots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, git submodules indeed doesn't support to import only a subdirectory of a submodule.

It is also not possible to set an environment variable to tell Webots where to find the PROTO files.

But here are a few possibilities to overcome your problem:

1. You can write a script to copy the PROTO files and controllers, this will save you from time-consuming and error-prone manual copy.
2. You can clone your robotA and robotB repos direclty in `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/robots`.
3. You can extend Webots to add this optional environmental variable definition, the list of PROTO files is determined here: https://github.com/omichel/webots/blob/master/src/webots/vrml/WbProtoList.cpp#L34
4. If you are on Linux, you can add a soft link from `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/robots/robotA` to your local repo folder where the `robotA` proto is defined.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you can add a soft link from `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/robots/robotA` to your local repo folder where the `robotA` proto is defined.

Comment: Thanks. However none of the possibilities fits the way I handle the projects. I moved all the protos and controllers to separate repositories, and imported them as submodules.

Comment: A new preference has just been added to Webots, it is now possible to define the path to an external directory where Webots will look for the PROTOs and controllers, this has been implemented here: https://github.com/omichel/webots/pull/233#pullrequestreview-207797930 and will be available in Webots R2019b (but you can always recompile Webots yourself from the develop branch).
Documentation of this new preference can be found here: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/preferences?version=develop#general